# Chrome Dev Tools pausing on rejected promise even though I'm catching it

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, es6-promise

I have the following typescript code where I throw a synchronous error from a promise creation function:

```js
function testExc(url: string): Promise<GLTF | undefined> {
    try {
        const promise: Promise<GLTF> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            throw Error('hi')
        })
        promise.catch((err) => { console.log(`Caught ${err}`) })
        return promise
    } catch (e) {
        return Promise.resolve()
    }
}
```

which to my surprise triggers a "Paused on promise rejection" in Chrome Dev Tools on the `throw` line. I have "Pause on Exceptions" turned on, and "Pause on caught exceptions" turned off because I want to know about uncaught exceptions.

Why is it pausing? I'm catching exceptions two ways: with the `.catch` and the `try/catch` around the whole thing. When I continue, the `.catch` stanza catches it as expected.

I'm using Chrome 80.0.3987.116 on Windows 10, with typescript 3.7.

The transpiled JS code looks like this, if it's helpful:

```js
function testExc(url) {
  try {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      throw Error('hi');
      resolve(undefined);
    });
    promise.catch(err => {console.log(`Caught ${err}`);});
    return promise;
  }
  catch (e) {
    return Promise.resolve(undefined);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465666) was raised in 2015 as a bug report for chromium.  Here are some relevant statements I can see in the discussion:

> The constructor callback is called synchronously before the ".catch()" code is executed, so at the time when the exception is thrown it is indeed uncaught. Later it becomes caught ... (aandrey@chromium.org)
>
> Try-catch scope is static. At the time of throw, we know that it's going to be caught. (yangguo@chromium.org)
>
> At the point the promise implementation checks and invokes the rejection handler can be a lot later. DevTools semantics require to break at the throw site though, to make any sense of "break on exception". (yangguo@chromium.org)
>
> So I guess the scenario we are discussing is the case where the Promise is rejected in the constructor ... In this case, there is no chance to attach a reject handler yet. (yangguo@chromium.org)

Long story short, when you throw an error inside a promise constructor, it's hard for devtools to identify that it is later handled.

Instead, handle it inside your constructor:

```
function testExc(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      throw new Error('hi');
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(`Caught ${e}`);
      resolve();
    }
  })
}
```